# Bootstrap - issue with navbar dropdown menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm learning bootstrap from youtube video series, and came to a bit of a problem. I'm trying to make a navbar with dropdown menu item. But this is what I get:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJJtQ.png

I went over the code, and I'm 99% sure it's the same as what Bucky had in his video, yet he got no such issue as I have.

Here is my code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tctki.png

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @miqro...https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/ and view source for an example

Comment: It's customary to post the code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your drop down isn't part of your navbar and is not associated with it.  You have find more information on the bootstrap documentation webpage but here is what your probably going to need.

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This can be found on at http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: Thank you so much sir. I don't know how I've missed that.